# get overlapping features informations on popup using WFS layer in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to get information from WFS layer that contain several overlapping features. i use this function to get information but i receive juste the information of the top feature.
Some one can help me ?

```
olMap.on('click', function(evt) {

var feature = olMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
});
if (feature) {
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var props = feature.getProperties();

    content.innerHTML = '<p><b>City</b>:'+props.nam+'<br> ZIP CODE:'+props.f_code+'</p>';
    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
}
else{
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont return the feature from `forEachFeatureAtPixel` method instead move `if` code inside the that method only.

```
olMap.on('click', function(evt) {

var feature = olMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {

    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var props = feature.getProperties();

    content.innerHTML = '<p><b>City</b>:'+props.nam+'<br> ZIP CODE:'+props.f_code+'</p>';
    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
});
```

Comment: It is correct to not return a truthy value from `forEachFeatureAtPixel`. But your code will not solve the problem either, because the content's `innerHTML` is overwritten with every subsequent feature. The result will be that the information displayed is from the bottom feature instead of the top feature.

Comment: Yes what your are saying is absolutely correct. But his code working on only one feature. He is not trying to add overlapping features to the `content`. I am not sure whether he want to show properties of all overlapping features or only one.